# Collatz Conjecture and the Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, collatz-conjecture

Let us define the two functions $F(n)$ and $G(n)$ as given:

$$
  F(n) =
\begin{cases}
3n+1 & \text{ and then dividing through by any powers of $2$}
\end{cases}
\\
  G(n) =
\begin{cases}
3n-1 & \text{ and then dividing through by any powers of $2$}
\end{cases}
$$

Assume for all $n$ we work with that 
$$G^{k}(n)=1 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad F^{k}(n)=1$$ for some $k$.

For example, $F^4(11) = 1$. Let us consider the set $\mathcal{O}(F) = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : F^k(n) = 1 \text{ for some k }\}$ and $\mathcal{O}(G)$ similarly.

Let's try to organize the sets as follows:

$$\mathcal{O}(F) \dashleftarrow\dashrightarrow \mathcal{O}(G)$$

For $$k=1$$
$1 \longleftrightarrow 1$

$5 \longleftrightarrow 11$

$21 \longleftrightarrow 43$

$\dots$
Notice these are all numbers which on their first iteration will go to $1$.
For $$k=2$$

$3 \longleftrightarrow 15$

$227 \longleftrightarrow 911$

$909 \longleftrightarrow 3643$

$\dots$

For any $k$  we can write

$a_1 \longleftrightarrow  b_1$

$a_2 \longleftrightarrow b_2$

$a_3 \longleftrightarrow b_3$

$\dots$

$a_i \longleftrightarrow b_i$

> Question: If the set of $\mathcal{O}(F)$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the set 
>   $\mathcal{O}(G)$, can we say there is a counterexample for $F(n)$ ? Because, There is a counterexample for $G(n)$ which that, they are $(5,7,17)$ and
>   $$\mathcal{O}(F) \dashleftarrow\dashrightarrow \mathcal{O}(G)$$

**P.S: Please help me for improve my question.**

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

No; any two infinite sets of natural numbers are in bijection with each other. In particular, any infinite set of natural numbers is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, even though most (all but one, in fact) infinite sets of natural numbers *don't* contain every natural number. Just knowing that $\mathcal{O}(F)$ and $\mathcal{O}(G)$ are both infinite, and that $\mathcal{O}(G)\not=\mathbb{N}$, doesn't tell you anything about what $\mathcal{O}(F)$ could be.

Comment: Though, set of $\mathcal{O}(F)$ is in **one-to-one correspondence** with the set 
$\mathcal{O}(G)$ ??

Comment: @Soru Yes. **Any two infinite sets of natural numbers are in one-to-one correspondence with each other.** ("In bijection with" is just another way of saying "in one-to-one correspondence with.")

Comment: Hmm...I understood thank you...

Comment: @Soru What does it mean for a *function* to be in one-to-one correspondence with another *function*? One-to-one correspondences are just for *sets*. And it is extremely easy to show that **any two infinite sets of natural numbers are in one-to-one correspondence with each other** (map the first element of the first to the first element of the second, the second element of the first to the second element of the second, ... , the $n$th element of the first to the $n$th element of the second, ...).

Comment: I understood 100% thank you so much!